# What specifically can’t the Wish spell do?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

Other than what’s described in the text of the [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell, are there any things that *wish* specifically cannot do? The one example I know involves [*​​mind blank*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank):

> Until the spell ends, one willing creature you touch is immune to psychic damage, any effect that would sense its emotions or read its thoughts, divination spells, and the charmed condition. The spell even foils *wish* spells and spells or effects of similar power used to affect the target's mind or to gain information about the target.

Are there any others?

Comment: I remember a general trend in 3.5 where defensive spells would generally be a level lower than the spell they defend against. It would make sense for 8th level spells to be necessary to foil _wish_.

Comment: It can't file your taxes for you. 

Answer (score 29):

### There is a list of things *wish* won't do

Even from the normal rules, there is a number of things that *wish* cannot do. In some cases, the rules call out that *wish* can do things only under certain circumstances, or limit the effect, which means that it cannot do them outside of these circumstances, or cannot do more. These cases include:

- Acquire the gem of a slaad, when the slaad is not present (MM, p. 274)
- Undo the effects of time warp from the Feywild for more than 10 creatures (DMG, p. 50)
- Repair more than 50 hit points of damage to *Dearn's Instant Fortress* (DMG, p. 161)
- Restore a soul imprisoned by the Void card of the *Deck of Many Things*
- Destroy the *Sword of Kas*, unless you also have the *Hand and Eye of Vecna* and are within 30 feet of it
- Restore a creature consumed by a Lich's phylactery to life - nothing short of divine intervention can do that (*MM*, p. 233)

#### By any means...

In addition, there are several effects that state that you cannot avoid them "by any means", and that includes *wish*, both because *wish* would be a means, and because there are other effects that state you cannot avoid them "by any means except *wish*". For example, *Divine Word* says a creature banished to its home plane

> can’t return to your current plane for 24 hours by any
> means short of a *wish* spell

This suggests that such a feature should say "except *wish*" if *wish* allows you to avoid it. Of course, this presumes a level of consistent editing that may not be always met in the rules, so your DM's mileage on this might vary. Examples include:

- Prevent taking damage from casting *wish* with an effect that is not one from the defined list (see also [Quadratic Wizard's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/210546/75095) for more discussion on this one)
- Put a warlock that has the Aspect of the Moon invocation to sleep (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 56)
- Move a ship anchored by a *Quaal's Feather Token*
- Prevent radiant damage to an evil creature by the *Book of Exalted Deeds*
- Restore a soul imprisoned by the *Book of Vile Darkness* to life
- Heal damage caused by Pale Tincture poison
- Escape the Chains effect of the *Imprisonment* spell

Comment: I'm not sure I buy the "by any means logic".  There are also things that the rules specifically say can't be done by a wish.  Similar logic would suggest that if the rules meant for something to be impossible, even with a wish, they would say so, as in these cases.  I find this argument more compelling than the "by any means" argument because the normal effect of a wish is to do things that are otherwise impossible. Your interpretation requires any description of a normally impossible act to be qualified with "except for wish" to avoid making it super-impossible. which seems implausible.

Comment: @Nobody Either "not by any means" means "not by any means [including wish]" or it means "not by any means [excepting wish]".  If it is the second, then the explicit "not by any means except wish" is redundant where it appears (and it does appear).  This answer (and mine), when faced with this choice opt for the 'rules do what they say they do' approach, where "not by any means" signifies exactly that and not an implicit 'of course, wish can always do the impossible'.

Comment: @Nobody First off, welcome fellow Nobody! Secondly, I agree, that is while I have the qualifier about editorial consistency. There however are several instances like the one I cite, so in multiple cases the authors felt they need to add „except by wish" to create that loophole. But you are right, it puts the same annoying burden on them, as it does on us when we answer questions about what is possible, or not.

Comment: @Kirt The argument works just the same in the other direction.  To wit, 'Either "not by any means" means "not by any means [including wish]" or it means "not by any means [excepting wish]". If it is the first, then the explicit "not by any means including wish" is redundant where it appears (and it does appear).'  Because wish is explicitly about doing things that are normally impossible, it makes more sense to explicitly call out the rules that wish can't break than to call out the ones it can. How many times do you expect rules writers to write "except for wish"?

Comment: @Nobody Absolutely the argument goes both ways.  Of "not by any means [including wish]" and "not by any means [excepting wish]", **one** of the two has to be redundant, and we certainly see both written.  However, I would argue that the principle of "rules do what they say they do" means that "not by any means", full stop, supports only one interpretation - where "any means" _includes_ wish, and "except for wish" is written as often as it needs to be.  My cursory search of the sources in my answer finds that "any means except wish" is less common than just "any means".

Answer (score 24):

#### Escaping Barovia

According to *Curse of Strahd*:

> No spell—not even wish—allows one to escape from Strahd's domain.

#### Avoiding the recoil from casting *wish*

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can’t be reduced or prevented in any way.

Various things deal damage which cannot be reduced by any means, but I'm citing *wish* specifically because you'd imagine that *wish* would mention if it protected against itself.

#### Communicating with Jhesiyra Kestellharp

In *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* p.10, the wizard [Jhesiyra Kestellharp](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Jhesiyra_Kestellharp) has used a *wish* to transform herself into a disembodied presence in Undermountain. However, it specifically states:

> But not even a *wish* spell or divine intervention will allow direct, two-way communication with Halaster's former apprentice.

#### Whatever else your DM says it can't

Of course.

Comment: The last paragraph should perhaps be emphasized more. While there are a number of specific lines that prohibit certain uses of Wish by RAW, when you look at the text of Wish ("The GM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance[...]"), it is clear to me that the overall intent is for the GM to make a decision on a case-by-case basis. Hence, there is no answer to "By RAW, what can I wish for?" - it is not a matter of RAW, it is solely a matter of what your GM says (which may be informed by RAW, but is not determined by it).

Answer (score 17):

### [Provisos](https://www.google.com/search?q=original%20aladin%20genie%20quid%20pro%20quo%20gig&sca_esv=be861b9490ff4bcf&rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS934US934&ei=gVjZZfqOJvf6kPIP_5yQkAc&ved=0ahUKEwi60__1-sKEAxV3PUQIHX8OBHIQ4dUDCBE&uact=5&oq=original%20aladin%20genie%20quid%20pro%20quo%20gig&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiJm9yaWdpbmFsIGFsYWRpbiBnZW5pZSBxdWlkIHBybyBxdW8gZ2lnMgkQIRgKGKABGAoyCRAhGAoYoAEYCjIJECEYChigARgKMgkQIRgKGKABGAoyCRAhGAoYoAEYCkjSFFDBBVjtEXABeAGQAQCYAXygAfMCqgEDMy4xuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIFoAKJA8ICChAAGEcY1gQYsAOYAwDiAwUSATEgQIgGAZAGCJIHAzQuMQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp&safe=active&ssui=on#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:6f8e2fe1,vid:pb0PuaikL4w,st:0)...

As listed in [Nobody's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/210547/23547), there are some things that a *wish* *can* do, but only under certain circumstances.  When those circumstances are not met, then, wish *cannot* do that thing.

For example, a *wish* explicitly can send the soul of a revenant to the afterlife when that soul is bodiless (MM 259).  It follows then that **a *wish* cannot dispatch the soul of a revenant that is currently embodied**.

Similarly, **a *wish* cannot return more than eight creatures from an altered time due to entering a sphinx's lair.**

### Not by any means...

As explained in [Nobody answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/210547/23547), some effects say they cannot be done or undone "by any means" while others say "by any means [except] wish".  *If* we assume that the former are things that a *wish* cannot do, than it cannot:

**Remove the "horns, a tail, or some other devilish features"** caused as a consequence of breaking a diabolic contract.  (BG:DiA 214).

**Raise from the dead** a creature whose soul is trapped on the soul spike armor of an intact infernal war machine. (BG:DiA 222)

**Permit entry to Xonthal's Tower** without passing through the extradimensional space that serves as its entrance. (TRoT 64)

**Return to life** someone who has been snuffed out and turned to a fetid powder through a combination of Acererak's crown and scepter (TftYP 224).

**Make brighter the eastern stairs** in the chapel of Kukulkan.  (TftYP 86)

**Obtain both the large and small sacks of the Siren** in the Cavern of Gold and Silver Mists.  (TftYP 222)